# Appendices and Bibliography in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, appendices

My document class is report. I am using chapters and sections within those chapters.

I have used the `\begin{thebibliography}` to create my bibliography, can someone tell me how I can add this to the table of contents?

Also I will be adding an appendex, can someone tell me how to create an appendix so that it shows in the table of contents?

Comment: I figured it out! It works with the command \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography} 

Thank you!!

Comment: `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}` would even be better, since `\bibname` normally contains the name of the bibliography in the current language setting